# Export sequences to fasta wide format

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, bioperl

I'm trying to export aligned sequences to a fasta file one by one using `Bio::SeqIO`.
The result is that the sequences are broken by a new line every 60 columns.
How do I avoid that?
I'd like to have the sequences exported in a 'wide' format, i.e. no line breaks in the sequence.

My code is roughly:

```
use Bio::SeqIO;
my $seqin = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "<$fastaFile", '-format' => 'Fasta');
my $outname = fileparse($fastaFile, qr/\.[^\.]*$/) . "_sub.fasta";
my $seqout = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">$outname", '-format' => 'Fasta');

while(my $seq = $seqin->next_seq){
      # do something with $seq
      $seqout->write_seq($seq);
}
```

Comment: Silly idea which doesn't really answer the question. But if this is just something you're only planning on doing once or a few times, you could probably throw together a one liner to remove the newlines. Something like, remove all newlines from lines which don't begin with ">". Then you could replace ">" with "\n>" to get the newline back before each header.

Comment: yep, that's pretty much what I ended up doing in the end. Just thought there might be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bio::SeqIO::fasta provides a [`width` method](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/SeqIO/fasta.pm#width) to specify how written FASTA records should be formatted:

```
while (my $seq = $seqin->next_seq) {
    $seqout->width($seq->length);
    $seqout->write_seq($seq);
}
```

Or of course if your sequences have some maximum size, you can just put a single

```
$seqout->width(5000);
```

or so in before the loop.